# PgRouting Driving Distance crashing postgis server

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, distance, driving

I haven't used PgRouting much so I'm a little in the dark here.  However, I am attempting a driving distance calculation like the one described by Underdark at [Catchment Areas with pgRouting driving_distance()](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/catchment-areas-with-pgrouting-driving_distance/).

My SQL is identical, I have a routable network etc etc.  I have also successfully run this in the past on another database.  However, when I run the simple piece of sql below, it completely crashes the PostgreSQL server with no error other than connection to server has been lost:

```sql
SELECT * FROM driving_distance('
      SELECT gid AS id,
          start_id::int4 AS source,
          end_id::int4 AS target,
          shape_leng::float8 AS cost
      FROM network',
      494902005,
      50000,
      false,
      false)
```

I first spotted the crash when trying to run this from Python.  I restarted the computer and tried to run the stripped down version above from PGAdmin.  It still crashes.  BTW the '494902005' value is my node id and I want to limit the search to 50km.  Because I am not getting any feed back, I don't know where to start diagnosing the issue.  I am using PostGIS 2/PostgreSQL 9.1 on 32bit Windows 7.

Comment: Which pgRouting windows binary do yo use?

Comment: It is one you compiled ("pgRouting-git-sanak-mingw_20120310_pg-9.1(x86)").  I believe this is the recommended one.  Do you think re-installing it would help or maybe try one of the experimental ones?  Also, many thanks for maintianing these Windows Binaries.  It is much appreciated as is your help!

Comment: I have just tried version "pgRouting-git-sanak-mingw32_20120703_pg-9.1(x86_32)" and I get the same result.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply. And I confirmed that this issue is reproducible after one source/target value changed to '494902005' with my "pgRouting-git-sanak-mingw32_20120703_pg-9.1(x86_32)". This may be unknown driving distance issue. So, I will investigate this issue, but if you hurry, try reduce source/target id values by Minimum value of (source/target).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of this issue is too high source/target id.

Out of memoery error occurred when vertices list is resized to '494902005' in "boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp" - "add_edge" method.
(See the following debug image's comment.)

[image]

So, it will be necessary to reduce max source/target value to proper one.